# How to call DB functions in Laravel Eloquent and use pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, function, eloquent

I'm trying to use Laravel 5.8 Eloquent with a custom function and raw sql

I have one table

```
Question(
id  integer
title string
description text
)
```

and this function in the controller

```
public function index()
{
    // go to the model and get a group of records
    //$question = Question::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    $question = Question::selectRaw(DB::raw('id,title,SUBSTRING(description,0,10) as description'))
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->paginate(3);
    return view('questions.index')->with('questions', $question);
}
```

My goal is to use pagination altogether with database functions like the example above.

The query works, the pagination works, 3 columns are returned `id`, `title` and `description` but the description is `empty`.

**What is the proper way to assemble the query?**

below is the dump

```
[original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 20 [title] => text [description] => )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `selectRaw(DB::raw(''))`, only `selectRaw('')` is fine:

```
public function index()
{
    $question = Question::selectRaw('id, title, SUBSTRING(description, 1, 10) AS description'))
        ->orderByDesc('id')
        ->paginate(3);

    return view('questions.index')->with('questions', $question);
}
```

---

**Update:**

I just went to MySql documentation and I saw this:

```
 A value of 0 for pos returns an empty string.
```

You should do this:

```
SUBSTRING(description, 1, 10)
```

More info on using `SUBSTRING`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

The problem here was not Laravel related, was a misunderstanding of MySql usage.

I think this will solve the empty problem!

Comment: I have already tried this, it is the same behavior, the description comes out empty

Comment: Can you confirm that the description is populated in the DB? When you run ```SELECT * FROM questions``` directly against the database, what you get? If you remove ```SUBSTRING``` and only retrieve ```description```, what you get? If you completely remove the ```selectRaw```, what you get?

Comment: it is populated, If I replace the code by `$question = Question::selectRaw('id, title, description')` it works (description is not empty)

Comment: that actually worked, sorry, never would have thought that

Comment: I did not get it at first too, it can happen to everyone. So many different languages and different rules. Sometimes we just let it pass.